# Better coding practice: if vs if not

Tags: python-3.x, coding-style

I have seen a lot of codes and I don't understand what is better practice to use `if` or `if not`.

I am putting an example here:

```
if result:
    return some_value
else:
    raise Exception
```

OR

```
if not result:
    raise Exception

return result
```

I just don't know which one is better practice and why. Would love to get your inputs.

Comment: This is probably better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but I will say that if you are concerned about one being more "efficient" than the other, as in one executing faster than the other, don't be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no so much difference in this case.
Some people can argue for one or another, but for Python there is no much difference.

p.e: I personally like more the second one due its simplicity but some people can argue that first is more difficult to corrupt into bad behavior by human error, where second one can be corrupted easily by adding a new indent in last line by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

The NOT construct is more difficult to understand, and in logic, gives us an infinity of variations.

When you go back to your code and make it more complex, the probability of an mistake increases exponentially.

Thats why code

```
if result:
    return some_value
else:
    raise Exception
```

is more relaible

Comment: I don't think not gives an infinity of variations. It can turn a true into a false or a false into a true - same number of variations though. It's also not difficult to understand, although sometimes a `not` is missed during a quick read-through. I suppose this is getting into the realm of opinions - which is why this question is probably not appropriate for SO in the first place.

Comment: @topsail  I agree that for the simplest type, which has only two states, there are no difficulties, and the difference is not felt. In addition, in computer science there is no infinity at all, each set has limits, either physical or logical.